# Как скрыть колонку на веб-странице с помощью расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension

Мне нужно скрыть или показать колонку с помощью моего расширения. Вот этот столбец я хочу скрыть/показать

[image]

У меня есть код:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chat GPT Column Hider",
  "description": "This extension allows you to hide the left column in Chat GPT.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://chat.openai.com/"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
function hideColumn() {
  // Get the left column element and hide it
  var column = document.querySelector('div.dark.hidden.bg-gray-900.md\\:fixed.md\\:inset-y-0.md\\:flex.md\\:w-[260px].md\\:flex-col');
  column.style.display = 'none';
}

function showColumn() {
  // Get the left column element and show it
  var column = document.querySelector('div.dark.hidden.bg-gray-900.md\\:fixed.md\\:inset-y-0.md\\:flex.md\\:w-[260px].md\\:flex-col');
  column.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<button id="hide-button">Hide Column</button>
<button id="show-button">Show Column</button>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**

```
// Get the hide and show button elements
var hideButton = document.querySelector('#hide-button');
var showButton = document.querySelector('#show-button');

// Add event listeners to the buttons
hideButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // When the hide button is clicked, call the hideColumn function
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'hideColumn();'
  });
});

showButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // When the show button is clicked, call the showColumn function
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'showColumn();'
  });
});
```

Получаем такой UI:

[image]

Но я нажимаю кнопку, получаю ошибку: *Uncaught ReferenceError: hideColumn is not defined*

[image]

Помогите пожалуйста как пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

В файле popup.html вы не подключаете файл background.js. Нужно добавить его подключение перед файлом popup.js и должно заработать.